# How to interface a vga monitor to fpga using verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, vga, virtex

I am using virtex - 5 fpga board and i am new in working with fpga board please suggest me any kind of material to have example codes for example to display a simple name on the monitor..

Comment: I think this question would do much better at [electronics.stackexchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Questions on Stackoverflow should be based on programming (even HDLs). This question covers hardware interface specs.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tutorial on a pong game that draws using VGA:

http://www.fpga4fun.com/PongGame.html